# Show minute progress by progress bar

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to use the [primefaces progress bar](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/progressBar.xhtml) to show a certain duration which is inputted by the user:

```
public Integer getProgress() {       
    if(progress == null) {          
        progress = 0;      
    }        else {          
        progress = progress + (int)(Math.random() * 35); //I giess that is now true for the example of 60 min
        if(progress > 100)          
            progress = 100;        }          
    return progress;  
}
```

This is what my ProgressView looks like at the Moment. Any recommendation how to change the progress bar to show for example a 60 minute duration?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bind your `value` attribute on your progress bar to `progress` in your backing bean and set the `interval` attribute to something suitable (it defaults to 300s)

```
<p:progressBar id="progressBarClient" value="#{bean.progress}" interval="10" widgetVar="pbClient" style="width:300px"/>
```

Reference

- [Primefaces Progress Bar VDL](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/4.0/primefaces-p/progressBar.html)

Comment: Thx for your answer! I do not get how to bind the value to progress and why to set the invtervall attribute? I would appreciate an example by you!

Comment: Are you new to JSF @mrquad?